# Expanding an Integrand

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve this integral but it looks like I do not get the right result. Can you please help me?

$$\int{(t-4)(t+2)^{\frac 4 5}}dt$$

I set $u=t+2$, so I get $\int{(u-6)u^{\frac 4 5}} \Bbb d t$ and then the solution I get is $$\frac 5 {14} (t+2)^{\frac {14} 5}-\frac{10} 3 (t+2)^{\frac 9 5} .$$

Can you please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Seems OK, remember when doing the substitution, you also have tu substitute the correct differential. In this case $dt=du$ so there is no problem.

Comment: You can check by differentiation. Looks good, apart from the missing ${}+{}C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks fine. Just some cosmetic things. You indeed get
$$\begin{align}
\int (u-6)u^{4/5}\; d\color{red}{u} &= \int u^{9/5} -6u^{4/5}\; du 
\\ &= \frac{5}{14}u^{14/5} - 6\cdot\frac{5}{9}u^{9/5} + \color{red}{C} 
\\ &= \frac{5}{14}(t+2)^{14/5} - 6\cdot\frac{5}{9}(t+2)^{9/5} + \color{red}{C}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: ok then it was just a question of simplifying my solution... I used an online calculator to check the result and it was different to what I got thats why. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\int{(t-4)(t+2)^{\frac {4}{5}}}dt
&=\int({t(t+2)^{\frac {4}{5}}-4(t+2)^{4/5}})dt\\
&=\int{t(t+2)^{\frac {4}{5}}}dt-4\int{(t+2)^{4/5}}dt\\
\end{align}$$
Subtitute $u=t+2$ and $du=dt$
$$\begin{align}
&=\int{(u-2)u^{4/5}}du-4\int{(t+2)^{4/5}}dt\\
&=\int{(u^{9/5}-2u^{4/5}})du-4\int{(t+2)^{4/5}}dt\\
&=\int{u^{9/5}}du-2\int{u^{4/5}}du-4\int{(t+2)^{4/5}}dt\\
&=\frac{5}{42}(t+2)^{9/5}(3t-22)+c
\end{align}
$$